# How to clone PyPI repository and maintain as local repo

Tags: python, anaconda, pypi

We have downloaded anaconda packages from https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/linux-64 to our local system and configured it as local conda repository. This is used to install conda packages on machines which dont have access to internet.

Same way would like to get all packages from PyPI and maintain a local repo. (some packages are only available in PyPI and not in anaconda).

Is there any repository from PyPI to download all the packages ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several options, see: https://packaging.python.org/guides/index-mirrors-and-caches/